# Tinymce - How to remove menu items,remove/edit menu headers

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is it possible to remove menu items in tinymce?
Also is it possible to remove an entire dropdown such as 'insert'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible to remove individual menu items.Please add following code to your tinymce init.

```js
      tinymce.init({        
         removed_menuitems: "undo,redo"    
    });
```

To get list of all menu items that can be removed - [link](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#menucontrols)

2. To remove/edit an entire menu dropdown please use the following configuration for the menu while initializing the tinymce.

```js
   tinymce.init({
      menu: {
        file: {title: 'File', items: 'newdocument'},
        edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
        insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr'},
        view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'},
        format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
        table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
        tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code'}
      }
    });
```